# Using the OVER clause in T-SQL to SELECT DISTINCT on all columns except one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have a table with colA, colB, colC, colD.  I need to SELECT DISTINCT on all columns except for colA.  I've found some examples that demonstrate the use of the OVER clause in T-SQL to achieve this; however, they have been pretty specific, and as such, difficult to apply to my situation.  Any insight anyone can will be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT colB, colC, colD FROM table`?

Comment: Please post some SQL statements that you have tried already.

Comment: If you need to select a, b, c, d and b, c, d need to be distinct, why not just `select max(a), b, c, d from mytable group by b, c, d order by whatever;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DENSE_RANK twice, one with ASC order, the other with DESC order, than add them up and subtract 1. That way, you got the SELECT DISTINCT with the OVER clause.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use OVER clause, as the comments suggest, use DISTINCT or GROUP BY. Anyway, to use OVER clause, check

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT colB, colC, colD,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY colB, colC, colD ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RN FROM TABLE
)
SELECT colB, colC, colD FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
```